# Transparency mask with gradient in OpenGL

Tags: opengl, transparency, mask, blending

is it possible to have a mask with transparency using a gradient in OpenGL?
I want to do something [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4pl8DcsCQ_k)

[image]

I achieved that with a Stencil buffer, but now I want to do that using a gradient, so the circle that is transparent, should be gradually transparent, and of course I can´t do that with Stencil.
I was thinking to use Blending but is it a better way?

So basically I have 
1) Background
2) Mask with gradient
3) Foreground

The background should only be seen when the mask is on top and should be displayed with a gradient

Comment: The mask can be a texture with an gradient alpha channel. Of course, the alpha channel of the mask can also be computed dynamically in the fragment shader.

Comment: So I should use BlendFunc and then compute the alpha channel on the shader?

Comment: Yes, that can be a solution.